# What is the physical significance of the cross product of curl of a vector field $v$ with another vector field $w$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, torque, vector-fields, vortex

I think if curl of a vector field v corresponds to an applied rotation, it's cross product with a velocity vector field w (say) should give something analogous to the resulting torque. Am I close?

Comment: It will be whatever the units of the result have at the end, torque has specific units you could check against at the end.